# Use Google font or host font myself

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

On my current project I am using a font which is currently hosted on googleapis.com. The font is "free" so I can get a copy and put it on my server.

My question is; is there any benefit to hosting it on Google vs having it on my own server? I've already got two other paid fonts hosted on my own server (using @font-face with fallbacks). So I was thinking of bringing the other font across, having it all in one place.

But I wasnt sure if there is anything I'm not considering? Is google fonts significantly faster/better performance etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google could be faster than your server depending on your server's bandwidth and load. However some negatives to hosting on google are:

- The Item could be removed leading to problems with your site
- googleapis.com could be an extra DNS lookup adding time to your site's load process
- I personally hate hotlinking

Positives:

- If dns entry is caches potentially faster proformance
- Less data use to your server

Answer (score 2):

A problem I've encountered with self hosting google fonts is that google serves different woff files for different OS and Browsers, sometimes even with the same name. This is due to different type rendering engines in Windows and OS that make perceptible differences in fonts width's between, for example, Chrome in Windows and Chrome in Mac. Let's say it's more complicated to self host fonts cross Browsers and os. [Here](http://typerendering.com/) is an interesting project focused on this type of subtile problems.

On the other hand it could be important to self host fonts in security-relevant sites.

Perhaps this would have merited only a comment, but I can not do it yet.